# How can both floating and outstanding shares of a company increase?

Tags: stock-market

A stock named 'HDFC Bank' listed on NSE (India's stock exchange) has shown an increase in shares outstanding and floating stock outstanding YoY. How?
[image]

Credits: TradingView

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Both floating (4.03-4.27-4.34) and outstanding shares(5.13-5.45-5.51) are increasing. How is that fundamentally possible, since the company didn't issue any new shares.

Answer (score 2):

Wanted to comment, but its too long with the links.

I think it's simply due to [ESOPs](https://www.hdfcbank.com/content/bbp/repositories/723fb80a-2dde-42a3-9793-7ae1be57c87f/?path=/Footer/About%20Us/Other%20stakeholders%27%20Information/19102019-grant%20ESOP.pdf).

For the effect on shares outstanding, see for example [Knowledge at Wharton - A business journal from the Wharton School of the University of Pennsylvania](https://knowledge.wharton.upenn.edu/article/how-employee-stock-options-can-influence-the-value-of-ordinary-shares/).

```
If a company had one million shares outstanding and employees exercised options to purchase 200,000 shares, there would then be 1.2 million shares outstanding.
```

Since float is always a portion of shares outstanding, both numbers go up.

On a side note, I am not sure if this question is well suited for economics but I am not sure [Money SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264169/where-is-the-community-to-ask-accounting-questions) or [Quant SE](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accounting) would be much better suited either.